# Add border to polyline google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to add border around a polyline the same as the following picture:
[image]

Can I do it, is it possible?
I have search the web for solutions for this problem and no so far.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trick would be to add two polylines, a thick black one that will do the border and a green one, less thick.

That way, because the green one is going to appear on top of the black one, but the sides of the black one are still going to be visible, it is going to act as a border.

Here's a sample of code to illustrate:

```
var border = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: 'black', // border color
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 7 // You can change the border weight here
});

var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path, // /!\ same path
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 4
});
```

Comment: @Brk I was just writing a similar answer. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/651/

Comment: Turnip thank you for the working example. I edited with a sample code, but see [Turnip's fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/651/) for a working example.

Comment: If you go for this approach just remember that rendering order is not 100% guarantee, so it's more reliable to actually set the z-index of each of your polylines using `Polyline.setZIndex(float)`

Comment: Had to use the zIndex mentioned by @NicolásCarrasco-Stevenson to make it work

Comment: As @NicolásCarrasco-Stevenson mentioned, I ended up using the `zIndex` option to get the border working: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#PolylineOptions